# HTML5 standards of nesting div in li or dl

Tags: html

I know that it is not allowed to nest div in li in HTML5, although you can and it works. Does that mean I shoudn't use it? What is the standard about nesting divs in dls?

Comment: Where have you "learned" that it is not allowed?

Comment: well, as far as I remember, the html validation in visual studio 2012 did not validate the code.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This information is incorrect - `div` elements are regarded [`flow content`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2) and are very well allowed inside [`li`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) elements. You might have confused it with `ul`/`ol` elements, which may only contain `li`s accordingly.

What has changed in HTML5 is, that it does not have block-level and inline elements anymore. Instead there is a more complex distinction of the [elements into several categories](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-models).

To see what is allowed inside an element according to HTML5, see the description of the specific tag where the section ["Content model"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-element-content-model) tells you which content is allowed inside this particular element.

#### EDIT: addressing the confusion in the comments about list elements

(according to HTML living standard as of 2019-07-30)

There are several types of lists - the most common ones are [unordered (`ul`)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element), and  [ordered (`ol`)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element) lists. `ul` and `ol` are the "container" elements that only hold [list item (`li`)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) as child elements - no other elements are allowed*. The `li` element itself can contain arbitrary [flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2).
<sub>* (technically they are also allowed to hold ["script-supporting" elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-2))</sub>

```
<ol>
   <li></li>
   ...more li elements
</ol>

<ul>
   <li></li>
   ...more li elements
</ul>
```

For [description lists (`dl`)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) there used to be the same restriction that they can only contain their respective child elements `dt` and `dd`, but recent changes allow `div` child elements as well, **as long as those `div`s themselves contain a `dt` or `dd`**.

```
<dl>
  <dt>term</dt><dd>description</dd>
</dl>

// the following is now valid as well:

<dl>
  <div><dt>term</dt><dd>description</dd></div>
</dl>
```

As a mnemonic: Container elements should only contain their respective child elements and those child elements can contain any content you like.

Comment: As far as I can see from what's written below dl, however, it can't contain divs. Am I looking at the right thing?

Comment: @sodium `dl` of course cannot, just as `ul` can't. `dt` and `dd` can.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate A `li` can hold flow content, `dl` (description list) can only contain `dt` or `dd` element which themselves can contain flow content (but `dt` no sectioning or heading content). It's the same like `ul` and `ol` which also can only hold `li` elements.

Comment: The above comments are incorrect. Based on the documentation in the accepted answer above, dl can contain divs, which can the contain the dt and dd elements. There is even an example of this on the page: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element

Comment: @maxandcoffee Since HTML is now a living standard, specs can change. You are correct, that `div`s are now allowed as child elements of a `dl`. I suppose this is to give some flexibility with frameworks and styling in general. However note the important paragraph putting the restriction in place, that the `div` itself must contain `dt` or `dd` or it will be ignored.

Answer (score 10):

It *is* perfectly allowed to nest `<div>` elements in `<li>` and `<dd>` elements. `<li>`/`<dd>` elements may contain *flow content*, which `<div>` elements are.

Specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element

Answer (score 1):

Since I had the same question as the second question: What is the standard about nesting divs in dls? I will answer here:

According to the HTML5 (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element),

> "The dl element represents an association list consisting of zero or more name-value groups (a description list). A name-value group consists of one or more names (dt elements, possibly as children of a div element child) followed by one or more values (dd elements, possibly as children of a div element child), ignoring any nodes other than dt and dd element children, and dt and dd elements that are children of div element children. Within a single dl element, there should not be more than one dt element for each name."

There is even an example of nesting divs inside the dl that wraps the dt and dd elements.