# Insert div and li before and after some elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$('.createcasedata').html(getHtml(data));
$( 'label' ).before( "<li class='ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit'>" );
$( 'input' ).before( "<div class='ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear'>" );
$( 'input' ).after('</div>');
$( 'input' ).after('</li>');
$('textarea').attr('class','ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-textinput-autogrow');
```

Want to achieve something like this :

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit">
    <label for="Test" mobile="" name="">Test Mobile Name</label>
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear">
        <input name="name" type="name" required="" calculated="false" len="150">
    </div>
</li>
```

What i am getting right now:

```
    <li class="ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit"></li>
<label for="Test" mobile="" name="">Test Mobile Name</label>
<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear"></div>
<input name="name" type="name" required="" calculated="false" len="150">
```

Please help

My data is:

```
<form id="caseform" action="url">
    <label for=Test Mobile Name>Test Mobile Name</label>
    <input name="name" type="name" required calculated="false" len="150" />
    <label for=Office Phone:>Office Phone:</label>
    <input name="phone_office" type="tel" len="100" />
    <label for=Website:>Website:</label>
    <input name="website" type="url" len="255" />
    <label for=Fax:>Fax:</label>
    <input name="phone_fax" type="tel" len="100" />
    <label for=Billing Street:>Billing Street:</label>
    <input name="billing_address_street" type="varchar" group="billing_address" calculated="false" len="150" />
    <label for=Shipping Street:>Shipping Street:</label>
    <input name="shipping_address_street" type="varchar" group="shipping_address" calculated="false" len="150" />
    <label for=Email Address:>Email Address:</label>
    <input name="email1" type="varchar" group="email1" calculated="false" len="" />Description:
    <textarea name="description" type="text" group="" id_name="" required related_module="" calculated="false" len="">Description:</textarea>
    <label class="select">Type:</label>
    <select name="account_type" type="enum" group="" id_name="" required related_module="" calculated="false" len="50">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Analyst">Analyst</option>
        <option value="Competitor">Competitor</option>
        <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
        <option value="Integrator">Integrator</option>
        <option value="Investor">Investor</option>
        <option value="Partner">Partner</option>
        <option value="Press">Press</option>
        <option value="Prospect">Prospect</option>
        <option value="Reseller">Reseller</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <label class="select">Industry:</label>
    <select name="industry" type="enum" group="" id_name="" required related_module="" calculated="false" len="50">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Apparel">Apparel</option>
        <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
        <option value="Biotechnology">Biotechnology</option>
        <option value="Chemicals">Chemicals</option>
        <option value="Communications">Communications</option>
        <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
        <option value="Consulting">Consulting</option>
        <option value="Education">Education</option>
        <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
        <option value="Energy">Energy</option>
        <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
        <option value="Entertainment">Entertainment</option>
        <option value="Environmental">Environmental</option>
        <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
        <option value="Government">Government</option>
        <option value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option>
        <option value="Hospitality">Hospitality</option>
        <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
        <option value="Machinery">Machinery</option>
        <option value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
        <option value="Media">Media</option>
        <option value="Not For Profit">Not For Profit</option>
        <option value="Recreation">Recreation</option>
        <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
        <option value="Shipping">Shipping</option>
        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        <option value="Telecommunications">Telecommunications</option>
        <option value="Transportation">Transportation</option>
        <option value="Utilities">Utilities</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <label for=Annual Revenue:>Annual Revenue:</label>
    <input name="annual_revenue" type="varchar" group="" calculated="false" len="100" />
    <label for=Employees:>Employees:</label>
    <input name="employees" type="varchar" group="" calculated="false" len="10" />
    <label for=SIC Code:>SIC Code:</label>
    <input name="sic_code" type="varchar" group="" calculated="false" len="10" />
    <label for=Ticker Symbol:>Ticker Symbol:</label>
    <input name="ticker_symbol" type="varchar" group="" calculated="false" len="10" />
    <label for=Ownership:>Ownership:</label>
    <input name="ownership" type="varchar" group="" calculated="false" len="100" />
    <label for=Rating:>Rating:</label>
    <input name="rating" type="varchar" group="" calculated="false" len="100" />
    <input id="mybutton" type="submit" title="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: use prepend and append instead of before and after. After inserts the element you have AFTER the element you are selecting. Append inserts the element INSIDE the element you're selecting.

Comment: Why not use `.wrap()` instead?

Comment: what you want is not a valid HTML markup.

Comment: You have the following in your code - `$('textarea').attr('class','ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-textinput-autogrow');` - your current output and desired output does not contain any `<textarea>` at all… can you be more specific and explain what exactly needs to be done..?

Comment: Jai, I think it might be ok in HTML5, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268907/html5-standards-of-nesting-div-in-li-or-dl

Comment: @Jai it works with jquery mobile so i am using it

Comment: @TilwinJoy there is a textarea in my main html  <textarea name="description" type="text" group="" id_name="" required related_module="" calculated="false" len="">Description:</textarea>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/9LNPb/1/

```
      $( 'input' ).wrap( "<div class='ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear'></div>" );
var divs = $("label , .ui-input-text");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=2) {
  divs.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<li class='ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit'>");
}
```

input

```
<label>Hi</label>
<input type="text">
```

output

```
   <li class="ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit">
       <label>Hi</label>
       <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear">
         <input type="text">
       </div>
   </li>
```

Comment: Its working but its ovverding all the elements on my page all of its css is coming out of place