# How can i display nav bar menu items and search button form inline block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display nav bar menu items and search button form in inline block where as it is showing in two rows.

Here is my code

HTML

```
                 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
        <form action="" class="search-form">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                   <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Cart</a></li>
               </ul>

                   </div>
                </div>

        </div><!--/.container-->
    </div><!--/.top-bar-->
```

CSS

```
 #header .search{
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar>.container .navbar-brand{
 margin-left: 0;
 }

.top-bar {
 padding: 10px 0;
 background: #191919;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
 line-height: 28px;
 }

.search-form .form-group {
 float: right !important;
 transition: all 0.35s, border-radius 0s;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

   .search-form .form-group input.form-control {
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: 0 none;
   background: transparent;
   box-shadow: none;
   display:block;
   }

  .search-form .form-group input.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   display: none;
   }

  .search-form .form-group input.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
 /* Firefox 18- */
 display: none;
  }
.search-form .form-group input.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
 /* Firefox 19+ */
 display: none;
 }
.search-form .form-group input.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
 display: none;
 }
 .search-form .form-group:hover,
 .search-form .form-group.hover {
 width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px 25px 25px 4px;
}
   .search-form .form-group span.form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
   right: -2px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
     height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #3596e0;
     left: initial;
    font-size: 14px;
   }
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yomozon/pLvp7ru0/)

Comment: Is putting your search form in your `ul` possible?

Comment: i don't think it is possible. in ul li we can't add div class i guess

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18269134/1064270

Comment: and you can also change your div to a span, or directly put your inputs in a li element

Comment: can you show me please how i can change div to span and then add it in ul li

Answer (score 0):

Placing the search bar beside the menu imply to cover it when the search form is expanded. So I may be broke a little your design, especially changed the width of `.col-sm-6`:

```
.col-sm-6{
    width:100% !important;
}
.nav.navbar-nav > li{
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    vertical-align: top;

    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#search-form{
    display:inline-block
}

.search-form .form-group input{
    transition: width 0.25s ease 0.1s;
    display:none;
}

.search-form .form-group{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.search-form .form-group:hover{
    overflow:visible;
}
.search-form .form-group:hover input{
    display:inline;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50vw;
    right: 0;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pLvp7ru0/3/

I think that you should add a better behavior to your search bar, you have to stay over it to keep it displayed. See the one on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS3).