# Can we put <dl> into <li>

Tags: html, html-lists, dd, dt

Is it semantically correct to put some **dl** (and obviously some dt / dd) into **li** ?

I know that we can put any block or inline elements into li but I do not know if it make any sense to put dl ,dt and dd

**EDIT** : I do not want to put any div in those elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 standards of nesting div in li or dl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268907/html5-standards-of-nesting-div-in-li-or-dl)

Comment: @lloydpick — Not a duplicate of that. That question is asking it it is valid, this question knows it is valid and is asking if it is semantically correct.

Comment: We can't tell if it makes sense to express your data in the form of a list of definition lists, we don't know what your data is. I can't imagine any data which would be appropriate to express that way though.

Comment: This is for the first child of a menu. My menu is an unordered list with list items and the first li has to give some informations (so the first li does not take part of the navigation). I want to align things buy using dd and dt but I am not sure it is semantically correct

Answer (score 0):

Ques Is Li block level or inline level element??
it is block level element by default as it takes the full width of line.
you can create a list then check in inspect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).