# Building menu with floated and non-floated list items

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

Using the html structure given in the code snippet (the structure can not be altered, I can just alter the CSS), I would like to achieve following menu layout:
[image]

But my CSS is causing a gap between "Item 1a" and "Item 2":
[image]

Don't know where this gap derives from and would like to know how to achieve the layout wanted.

```css
ul,
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

ul.menu li {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

ul.submenu li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

div {
  height: 0;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#1">Item 1</a>
      <div>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#1a">Item 1a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#1b">Item 1b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#1c">Item 1c</a></li>
          <li><a href="#1d">Item 1d</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed padding and margin from UL and LI, removed, height: 0 on the div. Seems to work. I stand corrected about DIV no allowed in LI.

```css
ul,
li {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

ul.menu li {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

ul.menu > li {
  float: left;
}

ul.menu > li > a {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu li {
  display: block;
}

div {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#1">Item 1</a>
      <div>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#1a">Item 1a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#1b">Item 1b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#1c">Item 1c</a></li>
          <li><a href="#1d">Item 1d</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Unforunately, the DIV can't be removed; but putting a DIV iside LI is allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268907/html5-standards-of-nesting-div-in-li-or-dl

Comment: Now, the column of "Item 1a" is unfortunately before "Item 1".

Comment: Now when running the snippet, the result is even more cumbersome.