# Treating <dd> like a child of <dt>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to do something like this:

```css
dt.red {
  color: red;
}

.red~dd {
  border-left: solid red;
}

dt.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.blue~dd {
  border-left: solid blue;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt class="red">Red</dt>
  <dd>Crimson</dd>
  <dt class="blue">Blue</dt>
  <dd>Azure</dd>
  <dd>Cyan</dd>
  <dt class="red">More red!</dt>
  <dd>Vermilion</dd>
  <dd>Scarlet</dd>
</dl>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GBC5PEYKTOJB But because the blue rule comes second, *all* `<dd>` after `class="blue` are blue.

I could use `.red + dd` if there would only ever be one, but there's often more than one. I could just wrap each segment in a `<div class="color">`, and I'll probably end up doing that.

But is there any other way? Something that makes each subsequent one overwrite past ones?

Comment: If you know an upper limit to the number of `dd`, you could brute-force it with `.red+dd, .red+dd+dd, .red+dd+dd+dd { ... }`.

Comment: You could consider that you have a list of lists here so nested lists would be semantically valid, particularly if you want more explicit grouping. One of the downsides would  be a fair bit more HTML

Comment: Yes I would suggest wrapping in a div like `<div class="color">`  too. You may solve it with CSS, but you would need some overly complicated CSS for that as answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working example

```css
.red {
    color: red;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}

dt, dd {
  padding: 5px;
}

.red ~ dd,
.red ~ .blue ~ .red ~ dd,
.red ~ .blue ~ .red ~ .blue ~ .red ~ dd {
    border-left: 3px solid red;
}

.blue ~ dd,
.blue ~ .red ~ .blue ~ dd,
.blue ~ .red ~ .blue ~ .red ~ .blue  ~ dd {
    border-left: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt class="red">Red</dt>
  <dd>after red</dd>
  <dd>Red also</dd>

  <dt class="blue">Blue</dt>
  <dd>after blue</dd>
  <dd>should be blue</dd>

  <dt class="blue">Blue</dt>
  <dd>should be blue</dd>
  <dd>should be blue</dd>

  <dt class="red">Red</dt>
  <dd>should be red</dd>
  <dd>should be red</dd>


  <dt class="blue">Blue</dt>
  <dd>should be blue</dd>
  <dd>should be blue</dd>


  <dt class="blue">Blue</dt>
  <dd>should be blue</dd>
  <dd>should be blue</dd>


  <dt class="red">Red</dt>
  <dd>should be red</dd>
  <dd>should be red</dd>

  <dt class="red">Red</dt>
  <dd>should be red</dd>
  <dd>should be red</dd>

  <dt class="red">Red</dt>
  <dd>should be red</dd>
  <dd>should be red</dd>


  <dt class="blue">Blue</dt>
  <dd>should be blue</dd>
  <dd>should be blue</dd>

  <dt class="blue">Blue</dt>
  <dd>should be blue</dd>
  <dd>should be blue</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Not sure how manageable this would be in the long term with the addition of additional colors etc.

Comment: There will only ever be 2 or 3 colors, although there could be a **lot** of `<dd>`. So yeah, not the best long-term, but an interesting workaround that I wouldn't have thought of; thanks for sharing!

Comment: @AzaAzdaema Welcome :) 
Thanks will be better if come with +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

How would I do it?

Be explicit with your classes. Add the classes to both the `dt` and `dd`. One of the shortfalls of definition lists is the lack of explicit grouping. You either need to acknowledge that short fall (<strike>don't wrap them in a `div` it's not valid HTML</strike> I take that back... [it is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268907/html5-standards-of-nesting-div-in-li-or-dl)) or come up with an alternative, which follows...

```css
dt.red {
  color: red;
}

dd.red{
  border-left: solid red;
}

dt.blue {
  color: blue;
}

dd.blue {
  border-left: solid blue;
}

dd.crimson { 
  color:crimson;
}

dd.azure {
  color:azure;  
}

dd.azure, dd.cayan {
  background-color:#333;
}

dd.cyan {
  color:cyan;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt class="red">Red</dt>
  <dd class="red crimson">Crimson</dd>
  <dt class="blue">Blue</dt>
  <dd class="blue azure">Azure</dd>
  <dd class="blue azure">Cyan</dd>
  <dt class="red">More red!</dt>
  <dd class="red vermillion">Vermilion</dd>
  <dd class="red scarlet">Scarlet</dd>
</dl>
```

Alternatively work with a HTML structure that give you grouping, in this case a nested list could work

```css
ul {
list-style:none;
padding-left: 0;
}

ul ul {
  padding-left: 40px;
  color: black;
}


li.red {
  color: red;
}

li.red li {
  border-left:solid red;
}


li.blue {
  color: blue;
}

li.blue li {
  border-left:solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="red">Red
    <ul>
      <li>Crimson</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">Blue
    <ul>
      <li>Azure</li>
      <li>Cyan</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="red">More Red
    <ul>
      <li>Vermilion</li>
      <li>Scarlet</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or wrap each group with a `div`