# is it apropriate to use <dl> for a list of skills?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantics

I'm writing an 'about me' page for my portfolio site, and I'm wondering if it's semantically correct to use `<dl>` for listing my skills. Something like this:

```html
<dl>
  <div class="flex-container flex-row">
    <dt>html</dt>
    <dd>clean,</dd>
    <dd>semantic,</dd>
    <dd>accessible.</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container flex-row">
    <dt>css</dt>
    <dd>flexbox,</dd>
    <dd>grid</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

or is it better just to use a `<ul>`? I'm mostly wondering what screen readers would do with it. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl#accessibility_concerns) is a little unclear.

thanks!

Comment: It's not "incorrect" but for what you have there, to me it reads more like a list of lists, so nested `ul` would be my choice. But this is somewhat subjective.

Comment: Also see [Utilizing the Underused (But Semantically Awesome) Definition List](https://css-tricks.com/utilizing-the-underused-but-semantically-awesome-definition-list/).

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer

The debate is mostly between definition list versus a serie of headings + paragraphs. Technically, they are often quite interchangeable without big consequences.

I would say that choosing one or the other should in fact depend on the length of the definition body.
If it is kept quite short, using a definition list is probably better. If the definition takes a whole paragraph, then it's probably better to go for headings and paragraphs.

IN your case, I would thus recommand to keep the definition list, as your "definitions" are quite short.

#### Longer answer

Behind that thinking about short=definition list, longer=headings+paragraphs, remember that screen readers have an option to navigate by heading:

- If there are a lot, that navigation becomes less efficient.
  You must use them for important parts of the page, but shouldn't overuse them to split too small parts. Hance something like your list of skills would probably produce too much noisy / quite useless heading, if you were using one heading and one paragraph per skill.
- IN the opposite side, if there are none or too few headings, that navigation comes useless, to. If the content of a DD become longer, in fact, your DT is "stealing" a heading, i.e. you should delimit that long DD part with an heading, so that it is possible to jump to it quickly.
  In your case your DD are rather short, so you aren't at all "stealing" any heading.

I was wondering whether `<div>` was allowed in `<dl>`, and yes it is according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268907/html5-standards-of-nesting-div-in-li-or-dl).
So go ahead and use a definition list.